What should I do if the `build.gradle` file in my Flutter project doesn't contain the `buildscript` class for adding Firebase dependencies?
I'm trying to configure Firebase with my Flutter project. However, I'm facing an error when I open the project's build.gradle file; it doesn't show me the buildscript function to add the dependencies. I have watched a lot of YouTube videos, but I haven't been able to find a solution, so I'm writing my problem here.
Here is the code of project's build.gradle file:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

That's the error:
Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services'] was not found in any of the following source
I have tried many times to add dependencies in build.gradle, but it starts with allprojects and there is no buildscript function present. I tried to manually add the buildscript function at the Android-level build.gradle, but it shows errors. What should I do?

try these steps and let me know if it worked:
Download the google-services.json file from your Firebase project settings. Place this file in the app directory of your Android project (android/app).
then Open your app/build.gradle file and change it like this:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' //Apply the Google Services plugin
}

and then run these commands in terminal while you are in the root directory of your Flutter project
flutter clean
flutter pub get


Still not getting solution, and showing the same error on the line id 'com.google.gms.google-services':
*What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services'] was not found in any of the following sources:

Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

